# How to shrink Columns to add new textview in 2nd line

Tags: android

I have to add textviews horizontally according to the data I have in my array. I am able to add textviews but they are coming in single line. I want to add new text view in next line automatically when the width of the view in overreached. here is my code to add the text views. I am Using Table Layout to add textview dynamicaly.

```
     TableLayout artistsView = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.artists);
    String[] array = JBUtils.getInstance().splitTextByComma(vo.getStarcast());
    TableRow row = new TableRow(_context);
    TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(params);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        TextView textView = new TextView(_context);
        textView.setText(array[i]);
        row.addView(textView);
    }
    artistsView.addView(row);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library: [FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout)

Answer (score 0):

Add Linear Layout to your layout param and set orientation vertically and add that linear layout to layout param.
Then add your New Textview to added Linear Layout.

Comment: This will add only one text view in one line.. I want that when the width is overreached then only it should add new text view in next line. This is not what I want.